# WPF C# - Set focus to the last item of ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, focus, itemscontrol

In my WPF application, I have an items control, which includes text boxes and I also have a button which adds a new item to the items control.
And I want that the focus will be set to the new item.

I tried

```
<TextBox FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
         Style=... />
```

and it works pretty good, but when I scroll in the ItemsControl, close the page and reopen it, cause of the FocusManager, the scrolling position will be on the bottom and not on the old scrolling position. It should just set the focus if a new item is added.

That is why I need another solution.

Comment: An itemscontrol has no scroller or selection. Think this must be a listbox of something.

Comment: The ItemsControl is inside a ScrollViewer

Comment: Please clarify, do you need either rewinding the ScrollViewer to the added element, or transferring the logical focus of the Window to it (FocusManager.SetFocused(window, object)), or both of these actions?
To use a ScrollViewer in an ItemsControl, it's better to override the ItemsControl template than to wrap the entire ItemsControl in a ScrollViewer.